# When will Linux kernel reset the signal handler for SIGSEGV to SIG_DFL?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, signal-handling

If I have set a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`, whereas a segmentation fault is generated like:

```
int *a = NULL;
*a = 1;
```

The handler will be invoked, but this signal handler will be invoked only once. So, I guess Linux kernel will reset the signal handler to `SIG_DFL`, but when? I want to know the details, so I checked the Linux kernel source code, but couldn't find the clue yet. Please show me the code if you know the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you register the signal handler.
With `sigaction` and without the `SA_RESETHAND` flag, there will be no resetting to `SIG_DFL` (although returning from a signal handler run in response to a `SIGSEGV` delivered due to a segmentation fault is technically UB).
With `SA_RESETHAND` it will get reset, and if you register the handler with `signal`, then whether the handler will be reset or not is unspecified (so don't use `signal()`).

Example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int volatile*a;
void h(int Sig) { write(1,"h\n", 2); }
int main()
{
    //sigaction(SIGSEGV,&(struct sigaction){.sa_handler=h}, 0); //won't reset the handler, will likely loop
    sigaction(SIGSEGV,&(struct sigaction){.sa_handler=h,.sa_flags=SA_RESETHAND}, 0); //will reset the handler
    //signal(SIGSEGV,h); //may or may not reset the handler
    *a=1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As rightly answered by @PSkocik, in normal scenarios kernel do not take trouble to change the signal action to default unless user have installed the signal handler with `SA_RESETHAND` flag in `sigaction`,.

However, there is a scenario where kernel do changes the signal action of `SIGSEGV` to default. Suppose, user has installed the signal handler and later exhaust whole memory before generating the signal. In this case, kernel will fail to create frame to execute signal handler as no memory is left. Upon sensing this situation kernel does the following:

1. Check if user has installed handler for `SIGSEGV`. If yes, changes the action to default also unblock `SIGSEGV` if user has blocked it.
2. Deliver `SIGSEGV` signal to user to terminate the user process.